# Beautiful Soup: Test if a div is children of a div

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to test with [Beautiful Soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) whether a div is a (not **necessarily immediate**) child of a div?

Eg.

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='aa'>
    <div class='aaa'>
      <div class='aaaa'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='ab'>
    <div class='aba'>
      <div class='abaa'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to test whether the `div` with class `aaaa`  and the `div` with class `abaa` are (not necessarily immediate) children of the div with class `aa`.

```py
import bs4

with open('test.html','r') as i_file:
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(i_file.read(), 'lxml')
div0 = soup.find('div', {'class':'aa'})
div1 = soup.find('div', {'class':'aaaa'})
div2 = soup.find('div', {'class':'abaa'})

print(div1 in div0)  # must return True, but returns False
print(div2 in div0)  # must return False
```

How can this be done?

(Of course, the actual HTML is more complicated, with more nested divs.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [find_parent](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent) method from Beautifulsoup.

```
import bs4

with open("test.html", "r") as i_file:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(i_file.read(), "lxml")

div0 = soup.find("div", {"class": "aa"})
div1 = soup.find("div", {"class": "aaaa"})
div2 = soup.find("div", {"class": "abaa"})


print(div1.find_parent(div0.name, attrs=div0.attrs) is not None)  # Returns True
print(div2.find_parent(div0.name, attrs=div0.attrs) is not None)  # Returns False
```

Answer (score 1):

try finding all the child elements using `find_all_next` and see if the child elements has the required class attribute.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")


def is_child(element, parent_class, child_class):
    return any(
        child_class in i.attrs['class']
        for i in soup.find("div", attrs={"class": parent_class}).find_all_next(element)
    )


print(is_child("div", "aa", "aaa"))  # True
print(is_child("div", "abaa", "aa"))  # False
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but what I want is actually: `print(is_child("div", 'aa', 'aaaa')); print(is_child("div", 'aa', 'abaa'))`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found a way. You gotta get all children divs of the parent div with `find_all`:

```py
import bs4

with open('test.html','r') as i_file:
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(i_file.read(), 'lxml')

div0 = soup.find('div', {'class':'aa'})
div1 = soup.find('div', {'class':'aaaa'})
div2 = soup.find('div', {'class':'abaa'})

children = div0.find_all('div')
print(div1 in children)
print(div2 in children)
```